# C++ - class method's won't to export from dll (VS - win)

Tags: c++, dll, dllexport, function

I've created example `C++` project in Visual Studio of dll type. It contains header file `SqlLtDb.h`:

```
 using namespace std;
    // This class is exported from the SqlLtDb.dll
    class CSqlLtDb {
    public:
        CSqlLtDb(char *fileName);
        ~CSqlLtDb();
        // TODO: add your methods here.
        bool SQLLTDB_API open(char* filename);
        vector<vector<string>> SQLLTDB_API query(char* query);
        bool SQLLTDB_API exec(const char* query);
        void SQLLTDB_API close();
        int SQLLTDB_API getNameOfClass();
    private:
        sqlite3 *database;
    };

extern "C" SQLLTDB_API CSqlLtDb* getInstanceCSblLtDb();
extern SQLLTDB_API int nSqlLtDb;
extern "C" SQLLTDB_API int fnSqlLtDb();
```

And in `SqlLtDb.cpp` methods are implemented as follows (I'm showing only two implementation):

```
...

int SQLLTDB_API CSqlLtDb::getNameOfClass()
{
    return 777;
}

extern "C" SQLLTDB_API CSqlLtDb* getInstanceCSblLtDb()
{
    CSqlLtDb* instance = new CSqlLtDb("");
    return instance;
}
```

`SqlLtDb.def` file look like this:

```
LIBRARY "SqlLtDb"
EXPORTS
getInstanceCSblLtDb
open
query
exec
close
getNameOfClass
```

SqlLtDb.lib file is generated by LIB command, using above .def file.
This is my SqlLtDb.dll file.

Now I want to include this file to my consoleApplication application.
ConsoleApplication is in VS 2008. I've set:

`Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies : SqlLtDb.lib;`

`Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library 
Directories: E:\PM\SqlLtDb\Release;`

Runtime Library is set as it was: Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd) (I didn't change it).

I copied files: `SqlLtDb.dll, SqlLtDb.lib, SqlLtDb.def, sqlite3.dll` into Debug folder where `consoleApplication.exe` is generated. And I added `SqlLtDb.h` file into folder where `consoleApplication's` source files are stored.

Function main in `consoleApplication` look like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "SqlLtDb.h";

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CSqlLtDb* mySqlClass = getInstanceCSblLtDb();  // here is ok, this method is 
                                                   // exported rigth
    mySqlClass->open("");  // here is error whit open method
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this code I get error:

```
Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: 
bool __thiscall CSqlLtDb::open(char *)" (__imp_?open@CSqlLtDb@@QAE_NPAD@Z) 
referenced in function _wmain consoleApplication.obj consoleApplication
```

Method `getInstanceCSblLtDb` is exported successful, but the problem is with export methods from class. I won't to export all class, better is export pointer to class.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export the class in the DLL with `__declspec(dllexport)`, and import it in the linking code with `__declspec(dllimport)`. Example:

```
class SQLLTDB_API CSqlLtDb {
    ...
};
```

You don't need SQLLTDB_API for each member, only the class - the linker will generate exports for each method for you.

Comment: I've changed it, but result is the same, unresolved symbol open

Comment: What happens if you remove the .def-file? It's not needed when you use __declspec(dllimport/dllexport). It could be interfering...?

Comment: This same, in both examples:  exporting class and exporting members of class. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.